# NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads not working for IP addresses

Tags: ios, https

excluding ATS on iOS 9 doesn't work for me.

I have a test server which has no domain name (IP address only) and no SSL certificate (so it is HTTP and not HTTPS)

Tried:

```
<key>52.24.145.252</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But I'm still getting the error:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary to your `info.plist`. Then add
`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to that dictionary and set the boolean value to `YES`.

[image: ATS Opt-out]

**Update**

From 2017 January, if you are using the above mentioned method for opting-out from ATS you need to provide a justification to Apple while submitting your app to AppStore.

[App Transport Security REQUIRED January 2017](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48979)

Comment: That might not be what you want. By doing this you are allowing all the HTTP request for any domain to be insecure. Have said that, I am having the same issue as Boaz, when I try to specify a specific domain.

Comment: @arjan 's answer below is a better answer to this question. This essentially removes the ATS feature, which is a good thing to have, while his whitelists the specific domains you need to support.

Comment: @kpsharp: The OP mentioned he doesn't have any domain name except some random ip address

Comment: This will not work without providing justification to Apple after 12/31/2016.  Disabling all of App Transport Security is overkill when there are other, safer options.

Comment: @wottle: At the time of asking this question, it was a valid answer and it will be valid after 12/31/2016 too, only change is they need to provide justification to apple when submitting the app.

Comment: Yes, thanks for updating.  I still think this is a bad idea in general in terms of app security.  I just want to make sure answers reflect the latest, especially when they are the accepted answer.

Comment: As of today March 20, 2017  `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` is not working

Comment: @themihai How have you validated that? It looks like it is supported according to the Apple Developer docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

[image]

Or, as source code:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Like that it works (given your domain is correct) in iOS 9.1.

Comment: This won't work with IP address.  Exception domains require domain names, and the OP only has IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I see you provided a workaround in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a great solution, but until Apple supports IP addresses, sometimes it is the only solution.  There is a long thread on Apple's discussion boards about this topic.

Comment: This worked for my problem which was not the same as the boaz since I have a domain name. Do you have a url for where all these plist settings are described?

Comment: If anyone is interested all the ATS plist settings can be found here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html under the heading ATS Configuration Basics

Comment: Would also like to comment my experience with Xcode 10, iOS 9.0, Swift 4+, that `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` set to `true` does NOT show as a dropdown option along with `Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content` or `Allow Arbitrary Loads`. It must be entered manually, for those of you, wondering...

Comment: yeah it wont work for ip, I am able to work with domain with this, but not ip. I need ip solution

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the real problem is that in iOS 9, ATS exceptions do not work with IP addresses.  It only works with domain names.  Turning off ATS altogether is a bad idea, and will cause you to justify that decision if you wish to submit to the app store after 12/31/2016.

Unfortunately, there is not a great solution to this short of trying to get a domain name for the server you are trying to connect to.

Others have had success using xip.io service to "convert" the local IP address to a domain name.  So you would add xip.io to the Exception domains, set the subvalue for `NSIncludesSubdomains` to true.  Then when you connect to your domain, instead of connecting to `52.24.145.252` you would connect to `52.24.145.252.xip.io`