# NSXMLParserErrorMessage Could not open data stream

Tags: ios, swift, rss, swift2, nsxmlparser

I built an RSS parser in Swift 1.x and it worked fine. But I recently switched to Swift 2. When I execute the same code in Swift 2 .It gives

> "Could not open data stream"

Even though the URL is correct. I tried several URLs and it also gives the same error.

Here is code:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml")!
parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
parser.delegate = self
var result = parser.parse()
let error = parser.parserError
```

**Update** : It works fine only on this url (http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss).

Comment: Did you added domain exception for ATS ?

Comment: thanks  @MidhunMP ,  I am not aware the domain exception. can I use hard coded  IP address in iOS9?

Comment: Yes, you can do that or just add exception for all domains. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695030/nsexceptionallowsinsecurehttploads-not-working-for-ip-addresses

Comment: @MidhunMP thanks , It is working :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Happy coding !!!