# How can I implement SSL Certificate Pinning while using React Native

Tags: android, objective-c, cordova, ssl, react-native

I need to implement SSL Certificate Pinning in my react native application.

I know very little about SSL/TLS let alone pinning.
I am also not a native mobile developer, though I know Java and learned Objective-C on this project enough to get around.

I started searching for how to execute this task.

### Doesn't React Native already implement this?

No, My initial search lead me to [this proposal](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-ssl-pinning-proposal) which has received no activity since August 2nd 2016.

From it I learned that react-native uses OkHttp which does support Pinning, but I wouldn't be able to pull it off from Javascript, which is not really a requirement but a plus.

#### Implement it in Javascript.

While react seems like it uses the nodejs runtime, it is more like a browser than node, meaning it does not support all native modules, specifically the https module, for which I had implemented certificate pinning following [this article](http://hassansin.github.io/certificate-pinning-in-nodejs). Thus could not carry it into react native.

I tried using rn-nodeify but the modules didn't work. This has been true since RN 0.33 to RN 0.35 which I'm currently on.

#### Implement using phonegap plugin

I thought of using a [phongape-plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin) however since I have a dependency on libraries that require react 0.32+ I can't use [react-native-cordova-plugin](https://github.com/axemclion/react-native-cordova-plugin/issues/35)

## Just do it natively

While I'm not a native app developer I can always take a crack at it, only a matter of time.

#### Android has certificate pinning

I learned that android supports [SSL Pinning](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) however was unsuccessful as it seems that this approach does not work Prior to Android 7. As well as only working for android.

### The bottom line

I have exhausted several directions and will continue to pursue more native implementation, maybe figure out how to configure OkHttp and RNNetworking then maybe bridging back to react-native.

But is there already any implementations or guide for IOS and android?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

After exhausting the current spectrum of available options from Javascript I decided to simply implement certificate pinning natively it all seems so simple now that I'm done.

> Skip to headers titled **Android Solution** and **IOS Solution** if you don't want to read through the process of reaching the solution.

## Android

Following [Kudo's recommendation](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-ssl-pinning-proposal) I thought out to implement pinning using okhttp3.

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .certificatePinner(new CertificatePinner.Builder()
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=")
            .add("publicobject.com", "sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=")
            .build())
        .build();
```

I first started by learning how to create a native [android bridge with react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)creating a toast module. I then extended it with a method for sending a simple request

```
@ReactMethod
public void showURL(String url, int duration) {
    try {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), response.body().string(), duration).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Succeeding in sending a request I then turned to sending a request pinned.

I used these packages in my file

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.CertificatePinner;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Kudo's approach wasn't clear on where I would get the public keys or how to generate them. luckily [okhttp3 docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.html) in addition to providing a clear demonstration of how to use the CertificatePinner stated that to get the public keys all I would need to do is send a request with an incorrect pin, and the correct pins will appear in the error message.

After taking a moment to realise that OkHttpClent.Builder() can be chained and I can include the CertificatePinner before the build, unlike the misleading example in Kudo's proposal (probably and older version) I came up with this method.

```
@ReactMethod
public void getKeyChainForHost(String hostname, Callback errorCallbackContainingCorrectKeys,
  Callback successCallback) {
    try {
        CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
             .add(hostname, "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
             .build();
        OkHttpClient client = (new OkHttpClient.Builder()).certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url("https://" + hostname)
             .build();
        Response response =client.newCall(request).execute();
        successCallback.invoke(response.body().string());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorCallbackContainingCorrectKeys.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Then replacing the public keychains I got in the error yielded back the page's body, indicating I had made a successful request, I change one letter of the key to make sure it was working and I knew I was on track.

I finally had this method in my ToastModule.java file

```
@ReactMethod
public void getKeyChainForHost(String hostname, Callback errorCallbackContainingCorrectKeys,
  Callback successCallback) {
    try {
        CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
             .add(hostname, "sha256/+Jg+cke8HLJNzDJB4qc1Aus14rNb6o+N3IrsZgZKXNQ=")
             .add(hostname, "sha256/aR6DUqN8qK4HQGhBpcDLVnkRAvOHH1behpQUU1Xl7fE=")
             .add(hostname, "sha256/HXXQgxueCIU5TTLHob/bPbwcKOKw6DkfsTWYHbxbqTY=")
             .build();
        OkHttpClient client = (new OkHttpClient.Builder()).certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url("https://" + hostname)
             .build();
        Response response =client.newCall(request).execute();
        successCallback.invoke(response.body().string());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorCallbackContainingCorrectKeys.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

### Android Solution Extending React Native's OkHttpClient

Having figured out how to send pinned http request was good, now I can use the method I created, but ideally I thought it would be best to extend the existing client, so as to immediately gain the benefit of implementing.

This solution is valid as of `RN0.35` and I don't know how it will fair in the future.

While looking into ways of extending the OkHttpClient for RN I came across [this article](http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2016/06/17/enable-tls-android-with-react-native/) explaining how to add TLS 1.2 support through replacing the SSLSocketFactory.

reading it I learned react uses an OkHttpClientProvider for creating the OkHttpClient instance used by the XMLHttpRequest Object and therefore if we replace that instance we would apply pinning to all the app.

I added a file called `OkHttpCertPin.java` to my `android/app/src/main/java/com/dreidev` folder

```
package com.dreidev;

import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.CertificatePinner;

public class OkHttpCertPin {
    private static String hostname = "*.efghermes.com";
    private static final String TAG = "OkHttpCertPin";

    public static OkHttpClient extend(OkHttpClient currentClient){
      try {
        CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
             .add(hostname, "sha256/+Jg+cke8HLJNzDJB4qc1Aus14rNb6o+N3IrsZgZKXNQ=")
             .add(hostname, "sha256/aR6DUqN8qK4HQGhBpcDLVnkRAvOHH1behpQUU1Xl7fE=")
             .add(hostname, "sha256/HXXQgxueCIU5TTLHob/bPbwcKOKw6DkfsTWYHbxbqTY=")
             .build();
        Log.d(TAG, "extending client");
        return currentClient.newBuilder().certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
      }
     return currentClient;
   }
}
```

This package has a method extend which takes an existing OkHttpClient and rebuilds it adding the certificatePinner and returns the newly built instance.

I then modified my MainActivity.java file following [this answer's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043581/907744) by adding the following methods

```
.
.
.
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.dreidev.OkHttpCertPin;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     rebuildOkHtttp();
  }

  private void rebuildOkHtttp() {
      OkHttpClient currentClient = OkHttpClientProvider.getOkHttpClient();
      OkHttpClient replacementClient = OkHttpCertPin.extend(currentClient);
      OkHttpClientProvider.replaceOkHttpClient(replacementClient);
  }
.
.
.
```

This solution was carried out in favor of completely reimplementing the OkHttpClientProvider createClient method, as inspecting the provider I realized that [the master version](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/OkHttpClientProvider.java) had implemented TLS 1.2 support but was not yet an available option for me to use, and so rebuilding was found to be the best means of extending the client. I'm wondering how this approach will fair as I upgrade but for now it works well.

**Update** It seems that starting 0.43 this trick no longer works. For timebound reasons I will freeze my project at 0.42 for now, until the reason for why rebuilding stopped working is clear.

## Solution IOS

For IOS I had thought I would need to follow a similar method, again starting with Kudo's proposal as my lead.

Inspecting the RCTNetwork module I learned that NSURLConnection was used, so instead of trying to create a completely new module with AFNetworking as suggested in the proposal I discovered [TrustKit](https://datatheorem.github.io/TrustKit/)

following its Getting Started Guide I simply added

```
pod 'TrustKit'
```

to my podfile and ran `pod install`

the GettingStartedGuide explained how I can configure this pod from my pList.file but preferring to use code than configuration files I added the following lines to my AppDelegate.m file

```
.
.
.
#import <TrustKit/TrustKit.h>
.
.
.
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


  // Initialize TrustKit
  NSDictionary *trustKitConfig =
    @{
    // Auto-swizzle NSURLSession delegates to add pinning validation
    kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @YES,

    kTSKPinnedDomains: @{

       // Pin invalid SPKI hashes to *.yahoo.com to demonstrate pinning failures
       @"efghermes.com" : @{
           kTSKEnforcePinning:@YES,
           kTSKIncludeSubdomains:@YES,
           kTSKPublicKeyAlgorithms : @[kTSKAlgorithmRsa2048],

           // Wrong SPKI hashes to demonstrate pinning failure
           kTSKPublicKeyHashes : @[
              @"+Jg+cke8HLJNzDJB4qc1Aus14rNb6o+N3IrsZgZKXNQ=",
              @"aR6DUqN8qK4HQGhBpcDLVnkRAvOHH1behpQUU1Xl7fE=",
              @"HXXQgxueCIU5TTLHob/bPbwcKOKw6DkfsTWYHbxbqTY="
              ],

          // Send reports for pinning failures
          // Email info@datatheorem.com if you need a free dashboard to see your App's reports
          kTSKReportUris: @[@"https://overmind.datatheorem.com/trustkit/report"]
          },

     }
  };

  [TrustKit initializeWithConfiguration:trustKitConfig];
.
.
.
```

I got the public key hashes from my android implementation and it just worked (the version of TrustKit I received in my pods is 1.3.2)

I was glad IOS turned out to be a breath

> As a side note TrustKit warned that it's Auto-swizzle won't work if the NSURLSession and Connection are already swizzled. that said it seems to be working well so far.

## Conclusion

This answer presents the solution for both Android and IOS, given I was able to implement this in native code.

One possible improvement may be to implement a common platform module where setting public keys and configuring the Network providers of both android and IOS can be managed in javascript.

[Kudo's proposal](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-ssl-pinning-proposal) mentioned simply adding the public keys to the js bundle may however expose a vulnerability, where somehow the bundle file can be replaced.

I don't know how that attack vector can function, but certainly the extra step of signing the bundle.js as proposed may protect the js bundle.

Another approach may be to simply encode the js bundle into a 64 bit string and include it in the native code directly as [mentioned in this issue's conversation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1093#issuecomment-98174954). This approach has the benefit of obfuscating as well hardwiring the js bundle into the app, making it inaccessible for attackers or so I think.

If you read this far I hope I enlightened you on your quest for fixing your bug and wish you enjoy a sunny day.

Comment: Just wanted to add: First, now there is also trust kit for [android](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android), and it has some benefits. Second, for some reason, the swizzling does not work for me on React Native on ios, still,cannot figure out why. And it look like there is no easy way to integrate it to Networking module like you did in Android.

Comment: Not sure this method works in RN 0.44.0. The client is replaced but Javascript can still make requests to pinned domains without valid pins being set.

Comment: If you're worried about the JS bundle being rewritten by a hacker, you should also worry about the app itself being rewritten, right? Under what conditions could one edit the JS bundle but *not* be able to edit the containing app that has SSL keys embedded?

Comment: This is a great answer but I have found out that will only work for requests using the `fetch` [API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.35/docs/network.html#using-fetch) in Android.
If you make requests using the `XMLHttpRequest` [API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.35/docs/network.html#using-other-networking-libraries) the certificate pinner will be ignored.

Comment: Many thanks for that detailed answer. Have someone found a solution for RN >= 0.43 ?

Comment: Now it's RN > 50.0 and I think we still need a solution to this :)

Comment: Android solution no longer works because of https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13777

Comment: From RN 0.54.0 it's available again https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.54.0 check this tutorial https://medium.com/@jaedmuva/react-native-ssl-pinning-is-back-e317e6682642 its almost the same as Amr Draz wrote

Comment: Any comment on this library: https://github.com/localz/react-native-pinch

Comment: For RN >0.5 better is to use setOkHttpClientFactory and implement OkHttpClientFactory

Set it up in the MainApplication onCreate() method
      
 OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(new OKHTTPIgnoreSSLFactory());

Comment: https://medium.com/@jaedmuva/react-native-ssl-pinning-is-back-e317e6682642
for react-native 0.56+

Comment: @MilosZikic, `setOkHttpClientFactory` is a great solution for android, is there any way similar to for ios native code?

Comment: @SaeedZhiany take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695030/nsexceptionallowsinsecurehttploads-not-working-for-ip-addresses

Comment: Is this still working? on iOS I'm not able to get it to work. Is there some issue with react-native 0.60 about this? I'm able to run it successfully on Android

Comment: Make sure to init TrustKit *first* in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` before RN bridge init. SSL pinning was not working for me in an iOS Release build until I made that change.

Comment: For future readers, I highly recommend following [this guide](https://itnext.io/react-native-security-ssl-pinning-cde086210d58). I used it to implement public key pinning on Android and IOS on latest RN version (0.64.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib https://github.com/nlt2390/react-native-pinning-ssl

It verifies SSL connection using SHA1 keys, not certificates.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work. I have a error: "Error: Failed isSSLvalid$ base64.js: 46: 18 ..."

Comment: @user3884677 have u tried to link "react-native link react-native-pinning-ssl" ? And if u r using Expo, u need to run "npm run eject" before linking.

Comment: yes I tried to link it and I don't use expo. You can see more detail in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160396/implement-ssl-certificate-pinning-while-using-react-native .

Comment: I've tried to create a new project and added this plugin, no issue at all. What version of your RN ?

Comment: btw, this plugin is react-native-pinning-ssl, the plugin in your link is react-native-ssl-pinning, they are different.

Comment: My version of RN is 0.56 . I tried the plugin react-native-pinning-ssl in a new project but I am the same error. It's right, In my example I tried another plugin but I also tried it you are talking about

Comment: for information, I had the same problem with IOS. I solved the problem by adding in the file RCTHTTPRequestHandler.m this code:

`- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}`

Comment: concerning the plugin react-native-pinning-ssl, I have the following error message: `"Failed isSSLValid$ index.js 10:10"`
I had to modify the compileSdkVersion = 26 in the cradle to integrate in my project

Comment: @user3884677 I can reproduce this error in android 4.4.4. Plz try with android > 5.0.0 while I'm debugging this. Thanks