# It is possible to secure my react-native application from MITM attacks?

Tags: security, react-native

I wish I could protect my application from MITM attacks over HTTPS, I know I can use [HPKP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Pinning_Cheat_Sheet) to protect the application.

Is it possible to do this from react-native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a package that seems to implement certificate pinning: https://github.com/localz/react-native-pinch. I haven't used it too extensively so I cannot comment on how convenient it is.

There's also a long write-up at [How can I implement SSL Certificate Pinning while using React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240321/how-can-i-implement-ssl-certificate-pinning-while-using-react-native) that walks you through implementing this yourself, based in part on https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-ssl-pinning-proposal.