# Implement SSL Certificate Pinning in React Native with the XMLHttpRequest API

Tags: android, ssl, react-native

I am currently implementing SSL Certificate Pinning for my React Native app.

I found a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240321/how-can-i-implement-ssl-certificate-pinning-while-using-react-native/40334166#40334166) explaining in detail the steps to archive this for both `IOS` and `Android`

But unfortunately the `Android` solution will only work as long as the requests are made with the `Fetch` [API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.35/docs/network.html#using-fetch) and I am trying to find a solution that also includes the `XMLHttpRequest` [API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.35/docs/network.html#using-other-networking-libraries)

Comment: Check this developer guide. Maybe it would help.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib https://github.com/nlt2390/react-native-pinning-ssl

It verifies SSL connection using SHA1 keys.

Answer (score 0):

SSL pinning is not a good practice at the app level because every certificate has its validity for a period of time. So the best way to pin certificate at server side. I have integrated the same in the case of Swedish bankid SSL integration in my react-native App.

Comment: fetch and axios will not work with ssl pining.You can follow this link.
https://blog.jscrambler.com/ssl-pinning/