# Why does preflight fail on newer Android devices but not older devices and desktop?

Tags: android, laravel, ionic-framework, axios, capacitor

- I am using the [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package to send API requests from my app to my backend
- The backend is built with Laravel and is a simple rest API
- If I run the Ionic app on desktop using `ionic serve` it works fine
- If I build an APK and install the app:

  - on an Android device with version 8 or below it works fine
  - on an Android device with version 9 or above the preflight checks keep failing

[image: preflight fail]

(This is using the remote devices feature by Chrome to inspect requests from the app)

- Initially, the requests wouldn't even send and it would error out before then and so I setup my network security configuration for Android and that removed the initial error but now it keeps failing on preflight
- My suspcion is that it might be related to the fact that the requests on the app are being sent from `http://localhost` but I'm not sure how to resolve this. Can you force it to use an SSL? If so, how?
- My CORS setup for Laravel is more leniant than the default CORS config that Laravel ships with:

```
return [
    'paths' => ['*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to SSL/TLS pinning which axios doesn't deal with as per [this comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1204#issuecomment-507053756).

[The Ionic Native HTTP plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) handles the pinning natively and that worked for but of course it makes use of Cordova which isn't available on your non-mobile devices.

There were two potential solutions:

1. Implement SSL/TLS pinning natively
2. Create a service/factory which determines whether we want to use axios or the native plugin

I opted for `#2` - if you want information regarding `#1`, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240321/how-can-i-implement-ssl-certificate-pinning-while-using-react-native).

The following method for me determines which HTTP wrapper to use:

```
static makeRequest() {
    return isPlatform('cordova') ? cordovaHttpService : axiosHttpService;
}
```

Of course, that can be amended with each specific case.