# Certificate pinning support in react native networking packages / axios

Tags: react-native, axios, ssl-certificate, certificate

I am using axios package for making api calls in my react native app. I now want to do certificate pinning to authenticate the api calls but I find no direct way in axios framework to pin the certificate even after a lot of searching.

So do axios package really not support certificate pinning ?

what is the proper way in react native to approach certificate pinning for api calls.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement SSL Certificate Pinning while using React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240321/how-can-i-implement-ssl-certificate-pinning-while-using-react-native)