# Some Files are not downloading?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i am using Mzdownload manager to download files but it sucessfully downloading https: Files
but it not downloading http files and showing error as UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://naasongsdownload.com/Telugu/2008-Naasongs.Audio/1-File/King%20(2008)%20-Naasongs.Audio/01%20-%20King%20-Naasongs.Audio.mp3, NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.,

```
availableDownloadsArray.append("http://naasongsdownload.com/Telugu/2008-Naasongs.Audio/1-File/King%20(2008)%20-Naasongs.Audio/01%20-%20King%20-Naasongs.Audio.mp3")
    availableDownloadsArray.append("https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9kgs6caztxxjdh/AlecrimCoreData-master.zip?dl=1")
    availableDownloadsArray.append("https://www.dropbox.com/s/73ymbx6icoiqus9/file2.mp4?dl=1")
    availableDownloadsArray.append("https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pw4jwiju0eon6r/file3.mp4?dl=1")
    availableDownloadsArray.append("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bmbk8id7nseirq/file4.mp4?dl=1")
    availableDownloadsArray.append("https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw7wfyaic9rtzwd/GCDExample-master.zip?dl=1")
```

I have Added below lines in  plist

```
`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

`
again same problem

and then i have added below lines

```
    ` <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourserver.com</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>`
```

but same problem

```
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>naasongsdownload.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        </dict>
        <key>www.naasongsdownload.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    
</dict>
```

my total updated plist

Comment: check this-: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi

Comment: i have tried that one tooo . but same issue

Comment: Try to add `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`

Comment: Did you changed `yourserver.com` to `naasongsdownload.com` in the plist. I know this is a silly question but just to confirm.

Comment: @savarala have you tried each and every answer in referred link? Have you also gone through comments, they are also very helpful.

Comment: @ViniApp i changed but same problem

Comment: @TusharSharma i have tried every anser in refered links

Comment: Did u tried with `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695030/nsexceptionallowsinsecurehttploads-not-working-for-ip-addresses

Comment: @ViniApp yes bro

Comment: To which target plist you are adding these changes in `Mzdownload manager` example?

Comment: Mzdownload manager example